# Edit a tableView entry in a separate ViewController an pass back the edited data into the tableView

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, segue

I am currently programming a diary app. Therefore I have all my entries listed in a tableView. One diary entry consists of a title, date, category and actually the diary content as a string.

All entries are stored in arrays like this:

```
var array = [Einträge] ()
```

To edit one entry, the data of one entry is passed to the "DetailViewController" by tapping on the entry in the tableView. I am currently able to change the different data, but i can't pass the changed data back to my tableView.

For showing the entry in the DetailViewController a segue is used:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let identifier = segue.identifier {
        switch identifier {
            case "AddEintragSegue":
                let destVC = segue.destination as! AddEintragViewController
                destVC.delegate = self
            case "Show Detail":
                let dVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
                if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell) {
                    dVC.eintrag = array[indexPath.row]
            }
        default: break
        }
    }
```

To save the Changes, this button have to be pressed. What should I add to the following Code?

```
@IBAction func btnSafeChanges(_ sender: Any) {

    eintrag = Einträge(name: txtTitel.text!, inhalt: txtInhalt.text!, datum: txtDatum.text!, kategorie: txtKategorie.text!)
```

Or should I use another type of segue?

Comment: You can use delegate to pass data back into table view controller and after passing Just reload table view

Answer (score 0):

You can go with some delegate to pass the data back

```
import UIKit

struct Einträge {}

protocol DetailViewControllerDelegate: class {
    func newEintragCreated(eintrag: Einträge, index: Int)
}

final class InitialViewController: UIViewController {

    var array: [Einträge] = []
    let tableView = UITableView()

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let identifier = segue.identifier {
            switch identifier {
            case "Show Detail":
                let dVC = segue.destination as! DetailViewController
                if let indexPath = self.tableView.indexPath(for: sender as! UITableViewCell) {
                    dVC.eintrag = array[indexPath.row]
                    dVC.index = indexPath.row
                    dVC.newEintragDelegate = self
                }
            default:
                break
            }
        }
    }
}

extension InitialViewController: DetailViewControllerDelegate {

    func newEintragCreated(eintrag: Einträge, index: Int) {
        // replace old object for newly created one
        array[index] = eintrag
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}

final class DetailViewController: UIViewController {

    var eintrag: Einträge!
    var index: Int?
    weak var newEintragDelegate: DetailViewControllerDelegate?

    func btnSafeChanges() {
        let eintrag = Einträge()
        if let index = index, let delegate = newEintragDelegate {
            delegate.newEintragCreated(eintrag: eintrag, index: index)
        }
    }
}
```